# Transforming layout page units to map units using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, layouts, vb

I am trying to build an add-in that will create a polygon from the current map extent. This is not a problem in Data View where I can easily get the envelope of an iMxDocument:iActiveView in data view.  I need to do the same in Layout view, preferably without switching back and forth between layout and data views.

When in Layout the iActiveView:Extent:Envelope returns an envelope coordinates of the map position with respect to the layout. (position of the map frame on paper so to speak)  How do I transform these into actual map coordinates?  I tried using iDisplayTransoformation:ToMapPoint but the input needs to be a screen point and the coordinates I have are of the map frame with respect to layout, not screen coordinates.

In other words i need to transform page units to map units whereas [iDisplayTransformation will transform only](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.1/java/arcengine/com/esri/arcgis/display/IDisplayTransformation.html) screen nits to map units or screen units to page units.

Comment: Possible info here: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=81739&mc=9#msgid221051

Answer (score 1):

Found it: iDisplayTrasformation:TransformRect

VB example in [Transform Rectangle from Page to Map Units](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/samples/Cartography/Display/7300e81e-424d-49d2-bdee-511f253bb7de.htm):

> You can use this function to transform an envelope (rectangle) from
>   page units to map units.

Comment: I wonder if that code does when the map is rotated slightly (IDisplaytransformation.Rotation != 0).  To handle that case, it seems like you'd need to use four corner points instead of a rectangle.  TransformPointsFI to get from page to device units, then TransformPointsIF to go from device to map.

Comment: Thanks @Kirk. That sounds like a better approach. I am running into some issues with the linked sample.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall - would you be able to add a code snippet or a link to one as a separate answer? The code in the link I posted gets me an envelope of the data frame when in layout but not the extent of the layout map frame.  I will add some visual to illustrate what I am after...